# Testing for null value in req.body

Tags: node.js, angular, null

In nodejs, my res.body may or may not include an 'attendees'. I want to do something if it has a value, or ignore if it doesn't. Here's a test below to check for 'null', can't understand why it isn't working:

```
        if(req.body.attendees)
            // do something
            console.log("TRUE: " + req.body.attendees); // returns TRUE: null
        else
            console.log("FALSE"); // should go to this branch but doesn't?
```

Comment: Please console.log the req.body.attendees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments refer that your trying to send a 'null' string in your post body, if it's the case, you should compare it like this:

```js
req.body.attendees == 'null'
```

if you're not sending the attendees parameter, or sending an empty value, your code should be working.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with this smelly check in the least.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a string and 'null' was the string value so had to test for if(req.body.attendees == "null") ...